# ROI submatrix is zero and Camera not showing proper video feed

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am working with 2 cameras in which I am facing the folowing error.The video from the left camera is coming clear and I have undistorted it as well as cropped it.You can see the image Below..
But during the video from my right camera even after doing the following steps I am getting the following output.Further the ROI Submatrix for the right image is coming out to be (0,0,0,0) due to which, when I run cropping, it forms a 0B image that is unreadable. The undistorted image is also coming out to be a zero matrix.(even though the camera's instantaneous feed is showing an output matrix).

Can anyone please help me as to why is this happening..??

Here are the values of calibration if you need:

```
camera_calibration for right camera:
intrinsics_left:[[ 780.74726423  ,  0. ,290.33118626],[  0. ,  779.17127666 , 207.80452343],[ 0., 0., 1. ]]
dist_coefs_left=[ -3.13470086e-01 , -2.21877052e+00   ,7.88813737e-04 ,  1.45019785e-03, 3.57425055e+01]
```

here's the data for right camera:

```
intrinsics_right=[[ 787.24858238 ,   0.          , 316.14950636],
                  [   0.         ,  791.01979331 , 278.32852384],
                  [   0.         ,   0.          ,   1.        ]]

 dist_coefs_right=[ -5.59376976e-01  , 5.94492949e+00  , 5.08561377e-03 , -1.54735229e-06, -3.08301921e+01]
```

[Click here to view image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByzXsElbUb6SM2dheVljVTB4WVU/edit?usp=sharing)

I am using tech-com computer webcams.Is there a calibration error? (because I have used the OpenCV provided code for calibration with a 7x7 chessboard)
Please help me . Thanks in advance

Comment: What calibration error did you get for the right camera? It seems calibration process for right camera failed (have you moved calibration plane during capturing, you've holded the chessboard in your hands during capturing)? And second: the same kind of device was used for left and right?

Comment: I've used the same set of images for calibration purpose for both camera's and both of my camera's are fixed to a stand which was not disturbed during the process. And ya both my camera's are same. And the error is 0.61 which is quite high.so now what should I do? Please help should I use some optimization technique to lower it..? @marol

Comment: Plus any ideas as to why region of interest is coming out to be zero ??